# AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest' test_get_server is not defined

Tags: python, django

!am trying to get the download and upload speed in python by using the "speedtest" module, but it gives me that error when I use the module:

AttributeError: module 'speedtest' has no attribute 'Speedtest'.

and I was only declaring the variable, that is my code :

```
import speedtest


test = speedtest.Speedtest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your .py file in the same directory as your script? Also how did you install speedtest?  If you installed it using `pip install speedtest` could you please try to unistall it using `pip uninstall speedtest` and then reinstall it using `pip install speedtest-cli`

Comment: didn't work bro @BigDog

Comment: Have you renamed your .py file? If it is called Speedtest.py it can conflict with the files that run, test.py could be a conflict.